# c# write to file try catches

Tags: c#, try-catch

This code works perfectly well. No issues with it.

The issue is that I would like to put a try catch block around it. This is what I have come up with. Can any suggest any more catches? Or is it fine the way it is?

```
String strFileLine1 = "This is a folder that will be used by the Virtual Flashcard program.";
String strFileLine2 = "Please do not delete.";
String myFilePath; 
.
.
.
SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFile.FileName = "FlashCard.txt";
saveFile.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
saveFile.ShowDialog();

myFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFile.FileName);
label2.Text = myFilePath;

try
{
    using (StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName))
    {
        fileWrite.WriteLine(strFileLine1);
        fileWrite.WriteLine(strFileLine2);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is a problem");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more catches"?  And why bother catching an exception if you're just going to ignore it?

Comment: If you check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt(v=vs.110).aspx) page you'll see `WriteLine` throws ObjectDisposedException and  IOException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap up this discussion. From @Erresen, "you're currently catching ALL exceptions with your current catch."

This is fine if you don't want / need to do something specific based on the specific exception received.

However, as @Johny Mopp mentioned, ObjectDisposedException and IOException are potential exceptions. Perhaps, if you have an IOException, you'll want to create an alert and notify the user that the method could not access the file, it was blocked, or wait a moment of time to try the file again.  But for ObjectDisposedException your only option may be to notify the user that the action is impossible. So you'll want to catch the exceptions individually and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for those who gave constructive criticism and help. To the others....

Here is the code that I came up with

```
SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFile.FileName = "FlashCard.txt";
saveFile.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
saveFile.ShowDialog();

myFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFile.FileName);
label2.Text = myFilePath;

try
{
    using (StreamWriter fileWrite = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName))
    {
        fileWrite.WriteLine(pushUp.StrFileLine1);
        fileWrite.WriteLine(pushUp.StrFileLine2);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(pushUp.StrIOExcepion);
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(pushUp.StrObjectDisposedException);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(pushUp.StrException);
}
```

Comment: The last catch, `catch (Exception ex) {...}` may be unnecessary. The MSDN article that @Johnny Mopp linked to states that the only exceptions thrown are the first two. And, unless I'm mistaken, you'll want to add a `finally` to close the file if it has been opened see: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/TryandcatchexceptionsforStreamWriter.htm